# How to add dynamic rows with dynamic id in table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a different rows with different columns . I want to add those dynamically.

As my code is

```js
$('.add-invoice-item').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    row += 1;
    var elem = $(".temp-tr tr").clone();
    elem.find('.alt_date').attr('id', 'invi_date' + row);
    $('.invoice-items').append(elem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody class="invoice-items">
</tbody>
<div class="temp-tr hidden-element">
<table>
<tr>
  <input type="text" name = "text1"/>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="text" name = "text2"/>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the problem now ?

Comment: I have different text in in both the rows .How I could add different rows dynamically .

Comment: Your example code is incomplete. Also please explain what your code does and what suppose to do. Good reading for start in SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask